# like button not incrementing count

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, button

What I want to do is for the 'like' button to increment the like_count parameter of the dest object. However, with the ajax call I'm currently making, the like_count parameter is not being incremented.

here is parts of my javascript file"

```
  Dashboard = (function() {
var trip_id;
// var apiUrl = 'https://planit-169.herokuapp.com';
var apiUrl = '';
var trip_id;
var create;
var submit;



/**
* HTTP GET request
* @param  {string}   url       URL path, e.g. "/api/smiles"
* @param  {function} onSuccess   callback method to execute upon request success (200 status)
* @param  {function} onFailure   callback method to execute upon request failure (non-200 status)
* @return {None}
*/
 var makeGetRequest = function(url, onSuccess, onFailure) {
   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: apiUrl + url,
       dataType: "json",
       success: onSuccess,
       error: onFailure
   });
 };

 /**
 * HTTP POST request
 * @param  {string}   url       URL path, e.g. "/api/smiles"
 * @param  {Object}   data      JSON data to send in request body
 * @param  {function} onSuccess   callback method to execute upon request success (200 status)
 * @param  {function} onFailure   callback method to execute upon request failure (non-200 status)
 * @return {None}
 */
var makePostRequest = function(url, data, onSuccess, onFailure) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: apiUrl + url,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onFailure
    });
};

/**
* HTTP DELETE request
* @param  {string}   url       URL path, e.g. "/api/smiles"
* @param  {function} onSuccess   callback method to execute upon request success (200 status)
* @param  {function} onFailure   callback method to execute upon request failure (non-200 status)
* @return {None}
*/
 var makeDeleteRequest = function(url, onSuccess, onFailure) {
   $.ajax({
       type: 'DELETE',
       url: apiUrl + url,
       dataType: "json",
       success: onSuccess,
       error: onFailure
   });
 };    

/** One-stop shop to update the dashboard. This will make the request to get
  * TRIP object, and pass it to the necessary call on click. Please put any
  * functions that need to be called here.
  */
 var updateDash = function(data) {
    var url = '/trips/' + trip_id;
    var onSuccess = function(data) {
        console.log("succesfully updated dash");
        updateHeader(data.trip);
        resetTable();
        initializeMap();
        insertAllDest(data.trip);

    };

    var onFailure = function() {
        console.log("something went wrong");
    }

    //if the ajax call has already been made
    if (data) {
        onSuccess(data);
    } else {
        makeGetRequest(url, onSuccess, onFailure)
    }
};

var updateHeader = function(trip) {
    console.log('updating');
    // var trip = data.trip;
    var users = trip.users;
    var user_count = Object.keys(users).length;
    console.log(trip);
    $('h1[data-header="location"]').html(trip.location);
    $('aside[data-header="invited-dates"').html("invited: " + user_count + " dates: " + trip.start_date + " - " + trip.end_date);
    $('a[data-function="invite-friends"').removeClass('hidden');
    $('a[data-function="form-save"').removeClass('hidden');
    menu_close();
}

var toggleElement = function($that, offset, toggle) {
    var height = $that.height() + offset;
    if (toggle === "down") {
        $that.animate({"top": '+=' + height}, 'slow','swing');
        $('.main-content').css('opacity', .5);
    } else {
        $that.animate({"top": '-=' + height}, 'slow','swing');
        $('.main-content').css('opacity', 1);
    }
}



/** =========================Destination Handler + Functions ============== */
var attachSubmitDestHandler = function(e) {
    submit.on('click', '.submit-input', function(e){
        e.preventDefault ();
        var name = submit.find('.name-input').val();
        var address = submit.find('.address-input').val();
        var dest = {};
        dest.name = name;
        dest.address = address;
        dest.trip_id = 1;
        dest.like_count = 0;

        var onSuccess = function(data) {
            if (!data.errors){
                console.log(data);
                insertDest(data["destination"]);
                submit.find('.name-input').val('')
                submit.find('.address-input').val('')
            }else{
                for (i in data.errors){
                    console.log(data.errors[i]);
                }
            }

        };
        var onFailure = function(data) {
            console.log("failure");

        };
        var that = this;
        url = "/api/destinations?trip_id=" + trip_id;
        console.log(url);
        makePostRequest(url, dest, onSuccess, onFailure);
    });

};

    /**
 * Insert dest into Itinerary List Table
 * @param  {Object}  dest        JSON
 * @return {None}
 */
var insertDest = function(dest) {
  // Find a <table> element with id="myTable":
  var table = document.getElementById("destTable");

  // Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the table:
  var row = table.insertRow(1);

  // Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:

  var name_cell = row.insertCell(0);
  var address_cell = row.insertCell(1);
  // var delete_cell = row.insertCell(2);

  var like_cell = row.insertCell(2);
  like_cell.innerHTML = '<input id="target" type="button" value="Like"</input>';
  //'<button id="target" type="button">Like</button>';
  //'<span class="likebtn-wrapper" data-identifier="item_1"></span>';
  //'<input type="button" id="add1" data-index="1" class="add" value="1+" title="Add"/>';
  var like_count_cell = row.insertCell(3);
  like_count_cell.innerHTML= dest.like_count;
  //'<div id="output" value =0></div>';
  //

  $('#target').click(function() {
    dest.like_count += 1;
    return dest.like_count;
    //$('#output').html(function(i) { return dest.like_count});
})


  // Add some text to the new cells:
  name_cell.innerHTML = dest.name;
  address_cell.innerHTML = dest.address;
  // delete_cell.innerHTML = "<div class='del'>x</div>";
  addMarker(dest.address,map);
};

var insertAllDest = function(trip){
    var d = trip.destinations;
    for (i in d){
        insertDest(d[i]);
    }
};

var resetTable = function() {
    $('#destTable tr').not('.table-initial').remove();
}

//function increaseLike() {
  //  dest.like_count += 1;
//}
/*$('#target').click(function() {
    $('#output').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
});*/

/*$(document).on("click", ".likebtn-wrapper", function(d,e,s){
    if(d.getElementById("likebtn_wjs"))
        return;
    a=d.createElement(e);
    m=d.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
    a.async=1;
    a.id="likebtn_wjs";
    a.src=s;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)})  (document,"script","//w.likebtn.com/js/w/widget.js");
}*/
/*function generateElement(index) {
return $("<input />", {
    type: "button",
    class: "add",
    value: index + "+",
    title: "Add",
    "data-index": index
});
$(document).on("click", ".add", function(e){
var newIndex = Number($(this).attr("data-index")) + 1;
var newElem = generateElement(newIndex);
$("#container").append(newElem);
}); 
}*/



/** =======================End of destinations handlers ======================= */

/** =========================End Handlers =====================================     */


/** ==MAP== **/

var start = function() {
    create = $(".create");
    submit = $(".submit");
    submit1 = $(".search-button");
    like = $(".like-btn");

    attachMenuHandler();
    attachLocationHandler();
    attachSubmitDestHandler();
    attachFriendHandler();
    attachCreateTripHandler();
    initializeSearch();
    attachLikeHandler();
};

return {
    start: start
};
})();
```

Comment: the snippet seems to be working just fine, did you get any errors after clicking and is jQuery available?

Comment: try using 
`$('#target').on('click', function() {
    $('#output').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
});` due to you creating the element dynamically it might not bind on the click event, the on event will listen for all events and fire on a specific one.

Comment: Can you post routes and controller code?

Comment: I just edited my code. Ideally, what I want to do is for the button to increment the like_count parameter of the dest object. However, with the ajax call I'm currently making, the like_count parameter is not being incremented.

Comment: Questions about debugging on Stack Overflow require a [mcve]. The code that you have posted is not minimal. Please [edit] your question to ensure that the code **in your question** is **Minimal** (only the code necessary to reproduce), **Complete** (all of the code necessary to reproduce) and **Verifiable** (we should be able to reproduce the issue using only the code in your question, nothing less and nothing more). As it is your question is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not completed.I guess target is dynamic added by code.When binding click event,target doesn't exist.

```
$(document).on('click','#target',function(){
     //TODO:
})
```